# Proof of upper and lower bound (Gilbert-Varshamov bound) for linear code

Tags: nielsen-and-chuang, information-theory, entropy, stabilizer-code

I am trying to prove the following bounds for a $[n, k]$ code that can correct $t$ errors

\begin{align}
1-H\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\geq \frac{k}{n}\geq 1-H\left(\frac{2t}{n}\right)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
H(x) = -x \log_2x-(1-x)\log_2(1-x)
\end{align}
is the binary Shannon entropy. I have two questions.

1. Are these bounds true for all $[n, k]$ code that can correct $t$ errors? For the lower bound, or the Gilbert-Varshamov bound, from the text around Eq. 10.63 in Nielsen-Chuang, it seems to be the case (see [here](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf)). However, from Gottesman, it seems like both bounds are true in certain asymptotic limits (see Eq. 1.15-1.20 in [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9705052)).
2. How to prove these two bounds? From the inequalities
   \begin{align}
   \frac{2^{nH(k/n)}}{n+1}\leq {n \choose k}\leq 2^{nH(k/n)}
   \end{align}
   which can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Approximation_to_binomial_coefficient), together with the following known bounds (see again Gottesman)
   \begin{align}
   \sum_{j=0}^{2t}{n \choose j}\geq2^{n-k}\geq\sum_{j=0}^t{n \choose j}
   \end{align}
   I was almost able to obtain something similar to the bounds, but not exactly the same. Any helps are appreciated!